# How do I implement an A* pathfinding algorithm, with movement costs for every programming language?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, path-finding, a-star

**Can we get people to post code of simple, optimized implementations of the A* pathfinding algorithm, in every single language?**

This is mostly for fun and to play with what stackoverflow itself is capable of... although I actually am interested in getting an ActionScript 3 version of this.

But the idea is that this "Question" will continue to be updated eternally into the future, even as different programming languages are created!

I don't know of any other place online where you can see pseudocode "translated" into many (much less every) different language. Seems like it's a worthwhile resource, and while not necessarily what this site was designed for, there's no harm in trying it out and seeing if it turns out to be a worthwhile thing that stackoverflow could be used for!

Comment: Would probably be better if you gave more ground rules such as a "test" maze/obstacle field.  Ideally each implementation would find the same route or a very common short-list of possible solutions!

Comment: @Ray Hayes, Maybe not the same route (as there can be multiple routes to the same goal), but the same length route.

Comment: The terms "optimized code" and "simple code" are mutually exclusive.

Comment: If you're looking for "place online where you can see pseudocode "translated" into many (much less every) different language" you're probably better off with [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Main_Page "Programming Chrestomathy"), a site actually made for that purpose.